# WebStorm NoInspection for Argument Type is not Assignable

Tags: javascript

I have the following error and I would like to suppress it.
[image]

There is no "auto" solution to it (ALT-Enter).

I already tried

- // noinspection JSValidateTypes
- // noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes

Any ideas?
Is there a JavaScript list for all noinspections?